# Save POST request body

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, post

I have a problem in saving very fast POST request. I have a BLE access point able to connect to internet and to send data through HTTP POST request. This AP collect data from several sensors and send as POST requests packets containing several parameter of each sensor as a list of strings. The request are sent very fast, less than 1 seconds. My aim is to receive these data (so manage POST request)  and save the body.
In this moment I have approached in a very simple way with Flask to receive:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route('/ble', methods=['POST'])
 def blePacket():
  dataPacket = request.json['data']

 
  


if __name__ == '__main__':
  # Start Flask server
  app.run(debug=True, port=8080)
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Would the exact example format that data you’re receiving be helpful?